# Why there is not full list of Skype notifications

Tags: skype, notification

After I reinstalled Ubuntu, I have the newest skype version installed now. And now I keep getting notifications at the right bottom corner, who came online, who went offline. I would like to get rid of these notifications, butt the problem is that problem is that at Options>notifications there is no such options like to turn off or on who came and who went out. 
What can I do about this? any skype parts missing or something?

Comment: i'm not sure if thats an askubuntu question, but anyway... You have a notification menu on skype options. just disable them there

Comment: @Geo You might want to post something like this as an answer (perhaps with information about how to get to the right place in the Skype options).

Comment: uh, i commented because i wasnt sure if that was an properly question, but sure.

Comment: To be honest, I scrolled up and down, maybe 10 times, and I didn't see "contact went offline" and "contact appeared online". It is me who should apologize for the question. Just need to keep my eyes open next time

Answer (score 2):

First open your Skype. If it's minimized in the systrem tray, click it and select `activate`.
[image: Activate]

Next into your Skype window, click on `skype` menu and then `options`

[image]

Go to the `notification` area.

Find `contact came online` and `contact went offline` and **uncheck** `Display pop-up notification` (and sound if you'd like).

[image]

Apply and you are done.